# Single word for "exceptional skill"

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a single word I can use to decribe someone who posesses exceptional skill--they are the cream of the crop, desirable talent. I want a word that jumps out from the page when you see it.

Comment: Hi Racquel. Single word requests and phrase requests (SWRs) require that the question contains maximum context. A good starting point is including an example sentence where the word would fit. Also think about what words you don't want, and why you don't want them, as well as how to describe the correct word. SWRs that do not have a definitive answer are not usually a good fit for the Stack Exchange format, as they solicit unqualified opinion.

Answer (score 1):

**singular**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/singular)

> being the only one of a kind; unique:

As in:

*He possessed a singular skill!*